# can a std::list contain different std::unique_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, stack, unique-ptr, stdlist

So, I'm making a game manager class for Qub3d Engine, and I want each `GameState` to be an `std::unique_ptr`

Each GameState such as `mainMenu` that I have is a child class of `GameState`

I need `std::list(or something)` to contain different unique_ptrs for each state such as `mainMenu` and `mainGame`.

I've tried `std::list< std::unique_ptr<GameState> > stateStack;`, but when I try to do this: `stateStack.push_back(m_mainMenu);` I get an C2664 error about the overload not including the mainMenu class. (Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using MSVC)

How would I accomplish this?
And is this even possible?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` to a base class can also handle a derived class. So make `std::list` of `std::unique_ptr` to the base class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `std::list<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> states;` ?

Comment: Do you really need std::list? std::vector won't do?

Comment: @DannyuNDos and @Galik I tried that, but I get an error about the overload not existing when I try to push_back the `mainMenu` class. @DeiDei as of right now I don't really care as it should work no matter which one I use, I'm probably gonna use vector though.

Comment: @TMcSquared What type is `m_mainMenu`? It must be `std::unique_ptr<GameState>` or `std::unique_ptr<mainMenu>`.

Comment: @DannyyuNDos m_mainMenu's type is mainMenu

Comment: @TMcSquared You cannot push a scalar object into a list of smart pointers.

Comment: er sorry, its a smart pointer of type mainMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, but you need to change how you think of pointers for this.

A `unique_ptr` meant as a guarantee that there will only be one pointer to the object. It manages the lifetime of the object it points to, and thus helps prevent possible memory errors and mistakes.

Thus, a `unique_ptr` should be *defined* within the context it lives. You can't just hand a random pointer to a data structure and have it *become* a `unique_ptr`.

In the terms of `std::vector`, you can use the `emplace_back()` function in combination with the `new` operator. This function actually handles the *initialization* of the object in question, as opposed to `push_back()`, which only adds an existing object to the data structure.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Dog>> dogshow;
dogshow.emplace_back(new Dog());
dogshow[0]->speak();  // outputs "woof", consistent with my Dog class.
```

Quite simply, the `emplace_back` function takes over the declaration of the `unique_ptr`.

If you absolutely want to use `std::list` instead, that offers an analogous `emplace` function. Many C++ standard data structures do.

---

NOTE: If you want the smart memory management of `unique_ptr`, but want to have multiple pointers to the same object, you should look at `shared_ptr`.